# How to avoid for loops and iterate through pandas dataframe properly?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, optimization, machine-learning

I have this code that I've been struggling for a while to optimize.

My dataframe is a csv file with 2 columns, out of which the second column contains texts. Looks like on the picture:

[image]

I have a function summarize(text, n) that needs a single text and an integer as input.

```
def summarize(text, n):
sents = sent_tokenize(text) # text into tokenized sentences
# Checking if there are less sentences in the given review than the required length of the summary
assert n <= len(sents)
list_sentences = [word_tokenize(s.lower()) for s in sents] # word tokenized sentences
frequency = calculate_freq(list_sentences) # calculating the word frequency for all the sentences
ranking = defaultdict(int)
for i, sent in enumerate(list_sentences):
    for w in sent:
        if w in frequency:
            ranking[i] += frequency[w]
# Calling the rank function to get the highest ranking
sents_idx = rank(ranking, n)
# Return the best choices
return [sents[j] for j in sents_idx]
```

So summarize() all the texts, I first iterate through my dataframe and create a list of all the texts, which I later iterate again to send them one by one to the summarize() function so I can get the summary of the text. These for loops are making my code really, really slow, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to make it more efficient, and I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

```
data = pd.read_csv('dataframe.csv')

text = data.iloc[:,2] # ilocating the texts
list_of_strings = []
for t in text:
    list_of_strings.append(t) # creating a list of all the texts

our_summary = []
for s in list_of_strings:
    for f in summarize(s, 1):
        our_summary.append(f)

ours = pd.DataFrame({"our_summary": our_summary})
```

EDIT:
other two functions are:

```
def calculate_freq(list_sentences):
frequency = defaultdict(int)
for sentence in list_sentences:
    for word in sentence:
        if word not in our_stopwords:
            frequency[word] += 1

# We want to filter out the words with frequency below 0.1 or above 0.9 (once normalized)
if frequency.values():
    max_word = float(max(frequency.values()))
else:
    max_word = 1
for w in frequency.keys():
    frequency[w] = frequency[w]/max_word # normalize
    if frequency[w] <= min_freq or frequency[w] >= max_freq:
        del frequency[w] # filter
return frequency


def rank(ranking, n):
    # return n first sentences with highest ranking
    return nlargest(n, ranking, key=ranking.get)
```

Input text: Recipes are easy and the dogs love them. I would buy this book again and again.  Only thing is that the recipes don't tell you how many treats they make, but I suppose that's because you could make them all different sizes.  Great buy!
Output text: I would buy this book again and again.

Comment: Instead of this code, can you provide some data in text and your expected output?

Comment: you might want to take a look at pandas.DataFrame.apply

Comment: `summarize()` calls another function. Can you include example input and output for this?

Comment: The first `for` loop can probably be removed with `list_of_strings = data.summary.values.tolist()`. Of course, this is not the approach to take as it takes it out of a dataframe but I'm curious if you've tried any pandas methods at all?

Comment: I will add an example input and output in just a second.

I've tried to pandas methods like:

`data['ourSummary'] = summarize(data['ReviewText'], 1)`

but obviously, it doesn't work.

Comment: Added the other two functions, but my computer is being incredibly slow right now so I can't provide the input and output texts. I'll do that as soon as I can. Sorry.

Comment: Provided the rest of the info. Sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
# Test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'ASIN': [0,1], 'Summary': ['This is the first text', 'Second text']})

# Example function
def summarize(text, n=5):

    """A very basic summary"""
    return (text[:n] + '..') if len(text) > n else text

# Applying the function to the text
df['Result'] = df['Summary'].map(summarize)

#    ASIN                 Summary   Result
# 0     0  This is the first text  This ..
# 1     1             Second text  Secon..
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Such a long story...

I'm going to assume since you are performing a text frequency analysis, the order of `reviewText` don't matter. If that is the case:

```
Mega_String = ' '.join(data['reviewText'])
```

This should concat all strings in review text function into one big string, with each review separated with a white space.

You can just throw this result to your functions.